# ffmpeg: How to scale .png over time

Tags: video, ffmpeg, png

I would like to slowly scale up a .png over 10 seconds, from start to finish.
I'm having trouble finding the solution. I am new to ffmpeg, and I don't seem to find any solutions to my issue.

`ffmpeg -i background.mkv -i img.jpg -filter_complex "[0:v]scale=1920x1080[bg]; [1:v] scale=-1:'480+(600*t)':eval=frame[top]; [bg][top]overlay=500:300" -vcodec libx264 out.mkv`

The .png is more or less at the center of the video. I'm using a solution that I found here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62845459/ffmpeg-scale-down-video-dynamically-squeeze-back-or-zoompan-out-to-smaller-tha
but I simplified the formula to just be linear (480+(600*t)).
This solution works if the overlay is just a video (.mkv or .mov), but doesn't work for a .png or .jpg.

From what I've experienced, zoompan only zoom in or out the image but it stays at the same scale. Am I missing something ?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

An image is treated by ffmpeg as a video stream with one frame. Loop it to generate a video stream of indefinite length. Set shortest flag in overlay filter to terminate output when the background video ends.

Use

`ffmpeg -i background.mkv -loop 1 -i img.jpg -filter_complex "[0:v]scale=1920x1080[bg]; [1:v] scale=-1:'480+(600*t)':eval=frame[top]; [bg][top]overlay=500:300"shortest=1" -vcodec libx264 out.mkv`

Comment: Thanks a lot! I just have a stuttering issue on the .png. Do you know how I can solve that?